# Is an infinite series only a limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

An infinite series is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$

This expression is equivalent to $\lim_{N->\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{n}$

Does this mean that an infinite series is nothing but a limit, rather than an actual sum?

Comment: Well, it's the limit of a sum - but yes.

Comment: Is this downvote appropriate?  I see no reason for this legitimate question.

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art Look at the questions this OP asks, you will understand that he/she asks many questions about more or less the same things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. If $s_N=\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$, then  $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n=\lim_{N\to +\infty}s_N$, as you pointed. So you can apply general theorems about sequences to series, if you adapt them accordingly to your needs.

Comment: So does an infinite series have an infinite amount of terms?

Comment: An infinite series is the limit of a certain sequence. You don't "add infinite terms", but only analyze the behaviour of the sequence of partial sums. Algebraic manipulations happen to work like we were summing infinite terms, so there's no loss in thinking of it like this.

Comment: What does the limit of N --> +$\infty$ (written in your answer) mean, if the number of terms in the sum is not infinite?

Comment: It means what it means: just a *limit*.

Comment: So an infinite series is the limit of a sum as the number of terms in the sum increases infinitely, but there is actually not an infinite amount of terms in the sum?

Comment: That's the gist of it. But as I said, there is no loss in thinking of it as the sum of infinite terms.

Comment: Why is there no loss in thinking of it as the sum of infinite terms?

Comment: @Math12345 See the second portion of my answer for why there **is loss** in thinking of it as the sum of infinite terms.

Comment: From what Ivo Terek from analyzing the behavior of sums of our series we can establish the notion of convergence or divergence if the limit exists

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases :

$1) $the series converges which means
that

$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{k=k_0}^Na_k \in\mathbb R (=L)$$

and we write
$$\sum_{k=k_0}^{+\infty}a_k=L $$

$2) $the series diverges and it has no sense to write $$\sum_{k=k_0}^{+\infty}a_k. $$

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question:

Yes, a series is defined as a limit.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n:=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$$

---

To answer some of your comments:

No, you cannot think of this as an infinite summation, for it does not obey the rules of normal addition.  [As I recently showed,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268345/find-the-value-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n-frac42n1/2268350#2268350)

$$\begin{align}0&=\color{#4488ee}{\frac11}-\frac11+\color{#4488ee}{\frac12}-\frac12+\color{#44ee88}{\frac13}-\frac13+\color{#44ee88}{\frac14}-\frac14+\color{orange}{\frac15}-\frac15+\color{orange}{\frac16}-\frac16+\dots\\&\stackrel?=\color{#4488ee}{\frac11+\frac12}-\frac11+\color{#44ee88}{\frac13+\frac14}-\frac12+\color{orange}{\frac15+\frac16}-\frac13+\frac17+\frac18-\frac14+\dots\\&\stackrel?=\frac11+\left(\frac12-\frac11\right)+\frac13+\left(\frac14-\frac12\right)+\frac15+\left(\frac16-\frac13\right)+\frac17+\left(\frac18-\frac14\right)+\dots\\&\stackrel?=\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac16-\frac14+\dots\\&\stackrel?=\ln(2)\end{align}$$

But clearly $0\ne\ln(2)$.

Notice however, that if you use the definition with the limit, then it is not possible to do all of the above steps... I'll leave it for readers to find which steps are not possible.

---

As a side note, there are other interesting ways to define an infinite series.  These are called regularizations, and one such example:

[$$\text{Abel sum:}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n:=\lim_{x\to1^-}\left[\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_nx^n\right]$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation)

This can be used to yield funky things like

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\left[\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^nx^n\right]\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\left[\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1-(-x)^{N+1}}{1+x}\right]\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\left[\frac1{1+x}\right]\\&=\frac12\end{align}$$

noting that $\lim_{N\to\infty}(-x)^{N+1}=0$ when $|x|<1$, which holds for $x$ close to $1$ on the left hand side.

where the equality is only true after regularization, since the original series does not converge in the normal sense.

Comment: In the first part, how do you know that the RHS is equal to ln(2)?

Comment: @Math12345 It is the alternating harmonic series, or the Taylor expansion of the natural logarithm.

Comment: In the first part of your response, what causes the inequality? 0 turned into ln(2). All I know is that certain terms were written differently and moved around.

Comment: @Math12345 Notice that I am pulling the positive terms faster than the negative terms, so they don't cancel like they should.

Comment: So order of addition matters, when there is an infinite amount of terms?

Comment: @Math12345 No, the important thing is to keep in mind that it is the limit of the partial sums.  That is the key.